# Why is my folder not being visible to the web? or upload-able?

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, chmod

For some odd reason I can no longer access my images in my image folder or any of its contents https://ksc105.kscserver.com/images/list.png or https://ksc105.kscserver.com/images/bold.png. I orginally could not upload files to images and attempted to use chmod a=rw /var/www/images but that did not help. I also upgrade php5 to the latest ubuntu build. What can I do to fix this issue, and what can I do to fix my upload issue?

The current images do not display becuase I get a 403 error:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /images/bold.png on this server.
> *Apache Server at [..].com Port 443*

Upload gives me:

> warning: move_uploaded_file(/[..].png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in [..]/images.php on line 37
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/tmp/[...].png' to '/var/www/images/nzoom.png' in [..]/images.php on line 37

*The [..] is just me taking out useless variables.*

PHP 5 on Apache 2 on Ubuntu 9.

Comment: @Tanner this is a poor suggestion and like saying "avoid problems with your locks by leaving your doors and windows all open"

Comment: @James: I didn't know the exact chmod, but I was just suggesting that for testing, to make sure it isn't anything wrong with you script.

Comment: @Tanner Already, got it solved! Thanks tho! I used chmod 757 *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you've messed up the permissions on the directory. You *probably* want to do:

```
# chmod 757 /var/www/images
# chmod 644 /var/www/images/*.*
```

to allow the nobody/apache webserver user to access them

Comment: Yes it worked... but I'm still getting this error Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/zoom_ksc.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/images.php on line 41 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpjLc1Po' to 'images/zoom_ksc.png' in /var/www/images.php on line 41

Comment: If you're lucky you'll be in the same group as the apache server so first try chmodding the directory to `775` if that fails use `757` instead.

Comment: Now to get attention to the other question I asked a week ago!

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions related probably most certainly. I suggest you chmod your:

- **files** to `0644` (or `0666` if Apache is not running as the same [FTP] user)
- **directories** to `0755` (or `0777` if Apache is not running as the same [FTP] user)

This way they will always be executable and you have further write permissions from within your scripts.

Comment: I think there's a typo there. Your first 777 should be 755

Comment: @James: Yes indeed, fixed it! Thanks. =)